# Signalling or signaling?

Tags: orthography, doubled-consonants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is “L” doubled?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338/when-is-l-doubled)

Most of the spell checkers are correcting it to be single `l`, from the other side many official technical documents/standards are using double `l`.

Answer (score 14):

Two Ls in British English, one in American English.