# Why do photons and protons exhibit such anomalous behavior?

Tags: phonology, stress, aspiration

I first noticed in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100198) that there is something sneaky going on with the word *photon*: its ‹t› is the **stressed allophone** of `/t/`, a fully **aspirated** `[tʰ]`.  It does not reduce to `[t]` or `[ɾ]` the way it does in words like *voting*.  Other words with the same issue include *proton* and *lepton*.

The only way I can explain this would be  if the second syllable in such words bears secondary stress, so  `[ˈfoʊˌtʰɑn]`.

Even so, the question remains: why does this happen? Is it because these are all “new” words? Or does Greek somehow enter into it?

I notice other new scientific terms have the related issue of an unreduced vowel in the syllable without primary stress, such as in *hadron, quasar, protein, baryon, genome*.

So the ‹t› in *proton* and *photon* works more like it does in *Motown* or *cow town*, but those are at morphemic boundaries.  The only “old” word I could think of where it might work the same way (remain aspirated) might be in *canton*.  But there the vowel in the unstressed syllable does seem a bit reduced, just not all the way.

What is really going on here?

---

**Edit**: The mid-word aspirated ‹t› also occurs in *futon* and *wonton* (as in wonton soup), but not in *Briton, Milton, tartan, titan, wanton* (as in a wanton woman).

Comment: I would suspect that as you suggest it's a combination of novelty and their being more clearly loan words than some others, means that they haven't been fully pounded into English. I don't have anything to back that up as an answer though.

Comment: Perhaps because the 'endings' in those second syllables, although bound, have lexical rather than merely grammatical force? Compare *proton/protean* or *photon/photic*.

Comment: I suspect it's the secondary stress. Everybody says /proʊtɑn/ and not /proʊtən/. If the second syllable didn't have secondary stress, you could reduce the vowel. Compare *crouton*, which also has secondary stress on the *on*. (And listening to some pronunciations on Forvo, *Avon* seems to in the U.S. but not the U.K.)

Comment: When I read this question initially I thought someone had accidentally posted a physics.SE question here!

Comment: *Photon* is "created" (1926 in modern sense) from the combining form φωτ- (phōt-) of Ancient Greek φῶς (phōs, “light”). Most "new scientific terms" have no documented pronunciation analysis, only a record of how it has been "historically" pronounced. As such an answer to this question would be subject to conjecture -- an open question. [cf. etymonline, wiktionary] On the same lines do *proton* & *lepton* follow.

Comment: For a rather drastically different scheme for naming particles, you might be interested in [Uncleftish Beholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncleftish_Beholding).  The words it uses for proton and photon are *firstbit* and *lightbit*.  :)

Comment: I've edited the tags to include [american-english] because the t-reduction detailed in the first paragraph does not generally apply to British English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I believe was a mistake: I know of no variety of regional English in which `[tʰ]` regularly occurs anywhere but at the onset of a stressed syllable. It’s the aspiration that is unexpected here. It doesn’t matter whether you reduce ‹t› to an unaspirated `[t]`, to a flap `[ɾ]`, or even to a glottal `[ʔ]`. As illustration, please consider the word *tatter* in RP: only the initial ‹t› is `[tʰ]`; the later one is merely `[t]`.

Comment: @starwed for trivia, renaissance 'polyglot' Walter Russell developed a [systemization of the subatomic structures](http://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/35_pt/pt_database.php?PT_id=147) with [proposedly] predictive power to [discover deuterium  and other](http://uvs-model.com/pictures/Russel_periodic_chart.gif)

Comment: @tchrist - your example, tatter, doesn't work in British English - the initial t is pronounced almost exactly as the second one, with a little more stress on the syllable. This question makes no sense in British pronunciation.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Yes it does! You are talking about flap-reduction, and I am talking about aspiration. See the difference?

Comment: nope - but happy to learn. Do you have any audio? To me they sound identical in British English (I understand the difference in US pronunciations)

Comment: @tchrist: Perhaps this will convince you that the t in *photon* and the t in *photos* are both aspirated in RP. I can't hear any difference in any case. Note that aspiration is stronger if the t occurs in the onset of a stressed syllable. http://books.google.nl/books?id=JSs-XyYukIoC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=british+aspirated+t&source=bl&ots=VvkVPqb4tz&sig=nmEsSUSrcJgeljqRSgnnKmqROtY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=52v8UN3LHZDltQbQoIHICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=british%20aspirated%20t&f=false What you describe is typical for American pronunciation.

Comment: @tchrist, and your observation is based on ...? Can we see your spectrograms?

Comment: @AlexB. I’m not sure which observation you mean, but I would love some spectrograms; fee free to provide. :)  **My observation — and question — is that the *t* in a few words like *proton* comes out aspirated as though it were in a stressed syllable onset, not an unstressed one.** The [link to Brian Cox on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZhZYtbPnag) at 8:43 shows him doing the same thing, so I really wish people would stop ranting about this being something they don’t do in the UK and poopooing it as a mere American phenomenon.

Comment: Is this behavior all **that** anomalous? Don't the words *protein* and *eighteen* do the same thing? Their second syllable has secondary stress (at least in AmE), which means the vowel doesn't get reduced and the *t* is aspirated.

Comment: I wonder whether the stress on the first syllable of two-syllable words like "proton" is induced somehow by some characteristic of the vowel in that syllable. If that were the case, then we might say that words like "proton" are actually have main stress on the second syllable -- which could account for the aspiration of /t/ between syllables -- but acquire stress on the first syllable. What might be conditioning the acquisition of stress? Perhaps it's vowel tenseness?

Comment: Should I realise now that pho-ton is not actually the name of a Vietnamese-style vegetable soup?

Comment: @tchrist, "The mid-word aspirated ‹t› also occurs in futon and wonton (as in wonton soup), but not in Briton, Milton, tartan, titan, wanton (as in a wanton woman)." How do you know this? Is it purely impressionistic?

Comment: Professor Wells summed it up pretty well "It is unfortunately the case that English aspiration is not a matter of all or nothing. In some positions voiceless plosives may have a certain amount of aspiration, but not enough to call them fully aspirated. The VOT in such cases is intermediate between that of “aspirated” voiceless plosives and that of “unaspirated” ones." http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/04/vot-is-more.html?m=1

Comment: Phonetics is not the same as phonology. Phonology is like gun control laws; Phonetics is like the NRA.

Comment: Regarding your examples: in my experience, _canton_ has an unaspirated <t> (like _Milton_, _wanton_, _tartan_, _button_), and _Briton_ has an aspirated <t> (like _futon_, _lepton_, _Motown_); also, while _hadron_, _protein_, _baryon_, and _genome_ lack unstressed-syllable-vowel reduction _by themselves_, the unstressed vowel _does_ reduce normally in, e.g., _hadronization_, _proteinoplast_, _baryogenesis_, _genomics_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bruce Hayes (UCLA) puts it,

> Word-medial voiceless stops are aspirated provided they are in the onset of a stressed syllable and are not preceded by a strident (Hayes 1995: 13).

Thus,

proton [ˈpʰɹouˌtʰɑn] in AmE.

There's no secondary stress in "voting" in AmE.

See a note on aspiration in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary (3rd ed., Wells 2008: 45) - those rules are rather comprehensive; at least, that should be enough for someone who's not a professional phonetician.

The most important thing to remember is that **aspiration is not binary**, aspirated or unaspirated, but rather gradual. See fig. 6.6 in Ladefoged 2006, A Course in English Phonetics.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is the suffix **-on** that causes the secondary stress to happen in most situations, like when it is added after a consonant.

This phenomenon is very common in AmE. But not the case in BrE: OBED and many other British dictionaries show otherwise (no secondary stress). [ Though [many British physicists still stress the word in a way that gives secondary stress on the second syllable](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZhZYtbPnag).]

[OE](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ion&allowed_in_frame=0) suggests that "**on**" made its first appearance in the early 19th century in atomic physics:

> **ion** (n.)  1834 [interestedly I've heard people pronounce it two ways: **ˈaɪən** and **ˈaɪˌɑn**]
>
> introduced by English physicist and chemist Michael Faraday (suggested by the Rev.
> William Whewell, English polymath), coined from Greek ion, neuter prp. of ienai "go,"
> from PIE root *ei- "to go, to walk".
>
> So called because ions move toward the electrode of opposite charge.

It was not until the late 19th century that [it is used as a suffix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron#History).

> In 1894, Stoney coined the term **electron** to describe these elementary
> charges, saying, "... an estimate was made of the actual amount of
> this most remarkable fundamental unit of electricity, for which I have
> since ventured to suggest the name electron". The word electron is
> a combination of the word electric(icity) and the Greek suffix "tron",
> meaning roughly 'the means by which it is done'. The suffix -on which
> is now used to designate other subatomic particles, such as a proton
> or neutron, is in turn derived from electron.

In the 20th century, it becomes a fashion to use it for coining new terms not only in physics:

> **proton** is coined in 1920 {it was used earlier in embryology (1893) at a translation of German anlage},
>
> **neutron** [**ˈn(j)uˌtrɑn**] is coined in 1921,
>
> **photon** (a particle-like package of light) is coined in 1926,
>
> **positron** [**ˈpɑzəˌtrɑn**] (the antiparticle of electron) is coined in 1933,
>
> **negatron** [**ˈnɛɡəˌtrɑn**] (the antiparticle of proton) is coined around 1933,
>
> **fermion** [**ˈfɜrmiˌɑn**] (any particle that follows the Pauli exclusion principle)
> and
>
> **boson** [**ˈboʊsˌɑn**] (any particles that don't follow the exclusion principle)
> are coined in the mid 20th century
>
> [A famous example of **boson** would be the **higgs boson** which may help us to gain a
> deeper insight into *dark matter* and *dark energy*, recently [discovered by CERN
> (though it is not exactly the higgs boson predicted by the *Standard Model*)](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-18702455)]
>
> **lepton** (any particle that does not undergo strong interactions but follows the exclusion principle E.g. electron) is coined in 1948
>
> **muon** [**ˈmjuˌɑn**] (an unstable, negatively charged lepton) is coined in the mid 20th century
>
> **gluon** [**ˈgluˌɑn'**] (an exchange particle responsible for strong interaction) is coined in the mid 20th century

but also in other branches of science:

> **interferon**
> [**ˌɪntərˈfirˌɑn**] *Biochemistry*
>
> a protein released by animal cells, usually in response to the entry of a virus, that has >the property of inhibiting virus replication.
>
> *1957, coined in English, so called because it "interferes" with the
> reduplication of viruses. From interfere + subatomic particle suffix
> -on.*
>
> ---
>
> **codon**
> [**ˈkoʊˌdɑn**] *Biochemistry*
>
> a sequence of three nucleotides that together form a unit of genetic code in a DNA or RNA >molecule.
>
> *1962, from code (n.) + -on.*
>
> ---
>
> **operon**
> [**ˈɑpəˌrɑn**] *Biology*
>
> a unit made up of linked genes that is thought to regulate other genes responsible for >protein synthesis.
>
> *1960s: from French opérer ‘to effect, work’ + -on.*
>
> ---
>
> **radon**
> [**ˈreɪˌdɑn**] *Chemistry*
>
> the chemical element of atomic number 86, a rare radioactive gas belonging to the noble gas series.
>
> *1918, from radium (q.v.) + -on suffix of inert gases. *

A very famous physicist, Richard Feynman, even used the prefix *-on* to make up his own word, "*parton*" when he explained a [seemingly-complex concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_%28particle_physics%29). And thus you can tell at that time the prefix *-on* was pretty well-used in the science community.

---

Notes: Not all 19th & 20th century scientific terms ending with "on" make use of the prefix "-on". One example would be **ion** as mentioned above, and here is another example

> **neuron** [**ˈn(j)ʊˌrɑn**]
>
> "a nerve cell with appendages," 1891,
> from German Neuron,
> from Greek neuron (see neuro-). Used earlier (1884) for "the spinal
> cord and brain."

---

Both the suffix *-on* and terms that exhibit secondary stress, such as *neuron*, *ion*, come from Greeks words.

So you are right, the Greeks are behind this.

Comment: You don't address why the popular British pronunciation does not stress the last syllable.  If the Greeks were behind it, then I think the Brits would have followed suit.  See Brit.: `/ˈnjʊərɒn/` *vs.* U.S.: `/ˈn(j)ʊˌrɑn/`.  I think you are closer with the French roots, which thusly drove the dialect per my answer.

Comment: @Arch You know, there might be something about *ion*.  It is an odd word, since it has two syllables. Similarly with *neon*, which also resists diphthongization. The *-on* particle seems a strong one, somehow.

Comment: @NewAlexandria You have to be careful there. Some people analyze any English syllable with an unreduced vowel as having at least **some** sort of stress, since unstressed syllables are supposed to reduce in English. If it were a schwa, then I would agree than it is unstressed, but as it has the CLOTH vowel, I wonder. Perhaps a better marker is the aspiration on the *t* at the onset of the  “unstressed” syllables, which is indeed why I chose the examples I did.

Comment: @tchrist I'm mostly arguing for French-dialectic influence in these pronunciation, since the British is absent of the stressing you've raised in the OP.  @arch also mentions the French connection, though his answer presents only US English pronunciations. See the Brit. `/ˈʌɪən/`, `/ˈʌɪɒn/` *vs.* U.S.: `/ˈaɪən/`, `/ˈaɪˌɑn/`

Comment: @tchrist yeah. I've watched many lectures (on Internent) and the professors always pronounce the particles with the secondary stress.

Comment: @NewAlexandria Yes I find that pretty weird too.. I think BrE follows the tradition more (like some pronunciation rules or something [I don't really know as I haven't gotten the time to study that]) while AmE just pronounces it as how it sounds in Greek. I'm not sure about the French influence though. Maybe there is connection.

Comment: @Arch Were any of these lectures by chance given by speakers originally from Britain or Ireland?

Comment: @tchrist I don't think so. Many are by Leonard Susskind and others I've forgotten who the lecturers are.

Comment: @Arch I think it behoves us to find one. That would settle the matter. Surely there must be something by Dawkins we can listen to.

Comment: @tchrist Sure! Dawkins talks more on biology so I couldn't find one by him yet. Here is a BBC programme by Brain Cox and it sounds like he has kinda stressed it but I am not very sure. (I'm not used to the British Accent). So you should have a look. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZhZYtbPnag He started mentioning proton, neutron and electron at 08:43.

Comment: @Arch Good find: I like Brian Cox. And you’re right, he definitely sounds like he is stressing the word *proton* in a way that gives secondary stress on the second syllable. It is not reducing, and it is aspirated. Strikes me as pretty clear confirmation.

Comment: @tchrist That's great. At first I thought I'd mistaken it as all British dictionaries suggest that there is no secondary stress but the aspiration can be heard.

Comment: Just so you know, the Community Wiki status of your posting, which happened because of it having been edited a lot, has no effect one way or the other on bounty awards. It would still go to you as the owner of the original revision. This is unlike how voting now works, where a CW post’s votes no longer affect your reputation.

Comment: Oh.. I shouldn't have edited it so many times. Is it possible to remove the Wiki status and recover the voting system?

Comment: @Arch You could perhaps try flagging it to beg a moderator’s indulgence and have them revert it back to a regular posting if they would be so inclined. However, I do not know how often this actually happens, or whether they have any formal or informal criteria that they use might have at their disposal to help them make — or perhaps more importantly, justify — that decision. I have seen it happen, although not too often. So I do not know whether they would look upon your petition kindly or not. You probably just have to convince them.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks! I've just sent a request. Hope they will help me and revert it back..

Comment: @tchrist Awesome! It has been reverted back!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your guess about Greek. The first "-ton" (in relation to particle physics) was the *proton*. [Ernest Rutherford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Rutherford) named the proton from the Greek πρῶτον, meaning "first".

Incidentally, Rutherford also had [William Prout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Prout) in mind when he named the proton and even suggested that one of two names be used: *protons* or *proutons*. Prout was the first person to theorize a fundamental particle of matter, which he referred to as a *protyle*.

As particle physics evolved, further discovered particles were named in a similar fashion. *Photons* are the elementary particles of light, and were named "φῶς  + ton". Most other elementary particles are named either for Greek words + "on" or "ton", or else after various physicists who had a hand in their discovery/description with "on" tacked on the end to indicate that it is a subatomic particle.

I also think your speculation about them being new words likely has something to do with their pronunciation. *Proton* began appearing in science literature in the 1920's. Every other subatomic particle name has been coined since then - these words are all less than 100 years old. They all originated after the invention of audio recordings, and none are used commonly enough to be changed by regional dialects.

Comment: Wilczek supposedly named the [axion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion) after a brand of bleach, on the basis that it *sounded* like a particle name.  :)  (I've heard him mention this at a talk, and I think you can check [this](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/276/5310/200.summary) article for confirmation.)

Comment: Great answer but I have to point out that ion (1834) is actually the word that influenced other physicists to name new discovered particles with the suffix -on [instead of "ton"]. Electron (1894) was later coined. After that then proton (1920) was coined. I study quantum mechanics and particle physics so I'm pretty sensitive to this :)

Comment: This answer only seems to cover US English. In UK English, there is no stress on the second syllable, and words like proton behave exactly as expected.

Comment: @RoryAlsop  Are you claiming that UK speakers do ***not*** aspirate the *t* in *proton*?

Comment: That makes no sense - what would the alternative be? Of course it is aspirated - it is a strongly defined t sound, as is the initial one.

Comment: Note also that the suffix/ending is -on, not -ton : the stem of Attic *phôs* "light" is *phôt-*, as can be seen in *photograph, photovoltaic, photosynthesis....* Note that the stem was *pha(e)-* in other dialects than Attic (cf. Greek *pharos, Phaethôn*); it is related to Greek *pha(i)n-* "radiate, appear", as in English *phaenomenon, phantastic...*

Comment: The suffix -one -- as in "ketone", "acetone", also seems to induce the unexpected aspiration.

Comment: Confused UK native speaker here. I pronounce the t in photon/proton the same as the t in voting.

Answer (score 1):

The OED acknowledges that the pronunciations differ between US and British usage:

- Brit. `/ˈprəʊtɒn/`
- U.S. `/ˈproʊˌtɑn/`

---

#### I will now speculate generously, but *precisely* ~~~

Words like *proton* rose in prevalence within the US populace during the race into the '[Atomic Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Age)'.  Texas, due to the wealth of oil tycoons and the [geological coincidence of petroleum and heavy metals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturally_occurring_radioactive_material), was the [hotbed of nuclear developments in the US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_A%26M_Nuclear_Science_Center).

Texas are known for their particular [*drawl*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawl).  The drawl is of French origin, and in the US became know as *Cajun*.  This French-speaking influence is the basis for much of what is known as the "Southern Dialect".  **Particularly**, this dialect is [known for emphasizing the second syllable](http://www.h2g2.com/approved_entry/A30501695):

> "Cajuns are quite distinct. They tend to place emphasis on the second syllable of a word, when possible. They use French words and phrases frequently in everyday speech. The names of Cajun cities and people often end in the very French suffixes '-ieux' and '-eaux', pronounced like a short 'o' sound"

Those familiar with the French style of speaking know that such words mentioned above, though 'short' in the Cajun dialect, are often emphasized.

Emphasis is often used for words of increased value or meaning.

---

As such, it is no stretch to conclude that the word *"proton"* would have garnered this attention by Southern speakers in the region, many of whom were staking business interest in booming nuclear operations - whose core science was based around the activities of Protons and other subatomic particles.

Comment: Could you please show phonetic transcriptions, not phonemic ones? Otherwise the distinction is lost.

Comment: @tchrist For how the drawl pronounces 'photon' and the like?

Comment: No, I mean for how you think the US and UK pronunciations are. I am looking for aspiration, remember.

Comment: Notice how in the link that Arch posted, it certainly sounds like Professor Brian Cox is saying *proton* with secondary stress on the second syllable.

Comment: I'll look for the same.  Someone in my family was born and raised in England + various part of the EU, has PhD science training - and doesn't pronounce words like 'proton' with a AmE stress on the last syllable.

Comment: [this lecturer stresses the first syllable](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WITlkLk6wzY) - probably Russian origin. [This UK presenter also stresses the 1st: 'Fo təns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hdKXMRKSY8). [but this Scot lecturer stresses the 2nd](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hdKXMRKSY8)

Comment: @NewAlexandria, in Russian in words like proton, electron etc. stress is always on the last syllable.