# Pronunciation Rule for "nt" in the Middle of Words

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, north-american-english

Is there a "rule" or pattern for the pronunciation of "nt" in the middle of words, followed by a vowel (or "er" sound)?

Here's what I have so far:

1) "t" is often omitted in words like "wanted," "mental," and "international" when "nt" is followed by a vowel or an "er" sound.

2) If the syllable following the "nt" is stressed, the "t" is pronounced: "integrity," "intoxicated," and "intact"

3) In words with "int," the "t" is sometimes obligatory, such as in "interrogation" and "interpretation," BUT it is not obligatory in others like "interception." The only pattern I see so far is that when the root word has a stressed syllable following the "nt," this carries over into the longer forms of the word. For example, "inTERRogate" is pronounced with a "t" and "interrogation" is also pronounced with a "t" (even though the syllable following the "nt" is no longer stressed).

4) In words like "attention," the "ti" is pronounced as /ʃ/ ("sh").

Can anyone think of additional examples or rules? Are there any examples which would contradict my reasoning so far?

Comment: In _interrogation_ and _interpretation_, it is perhaps not so much that the roots have stressed syllables after, but that the words themselves have secondarily stressed syllables after.

Comment: As @Janus said, people usually analyze English as having "secondary stress" on certain syllables of polysyllabic words (usually it can't appear adjacent to primary stress; stress often occurs in an alternating pattern). Syllables with secondary stress are immune to certain lenition processes (another example of this is that the vowel of a syllable with secondary stress cannot be reduced to schwa).

Comment: More on secondary stress in the following post: [Why do photons and protons exhibit such anomalous behavior?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100210/why-do-photons-and-protons-exhibit-such-anomalous-behavior) (Those are examples of words that do in fact have secondary stress right next to primary stress; it is possible, although as I said not preferred.)

Comment: The rules may go on and on with regional variations. Are you sure that 'mental' and 'international' lose the 't' rather than soften it, so it's drier than a 't' but more than just a glottal stop?

Comment: simple. **nt** combo which closes a stressed syllable turns into just *n*. Internet, International, Wanted, Mental, Advantage, Environmental, Interaction and many many more. depending on how articulate the american wants to sound, he may choose to fully pronounce the T as a true T.

Comment: I know that the question is about American English but in British English users of Recieved Pronunciation would consider dropping or merging of the 't' sound in any of those examples to be 'casual'; 'lazy'; 'horribly working class'; or, worst of all 'American'. Sorry, I jest.

Comment: Can any BrE speakers/investigators comment on how BrE doesn't (or does?) drop the t?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to **nt** reduction to **n** in American English that results in *winter* and *winner* being pronounced the same, there is an entry in J. C. Wells' blog about it:

http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/11/winter-and-winner.html

Here are the most relevant extracts:

> - The environments in which nt-reduction operates seem to be the same as those for t-voicing. In particular, it does not happen in the environment of a following stressed vowel, as in *intend*, *contain*, nor of a following unstressed but strong vowel as in *intake*; nor does it apply to **ntr** clusters, as in *country*. The t can be lost in *centre*/*center* but not in *central*.
> - Some words may be special cases, In particular, I have the impression that *ninety* in AmE is often **ˈnaɪndi** rather than the expected **ˈnaɪnti** or **ˈnaɪni**. Does the same apply to *seventy*? Are there other exceptional cases?

There is also the case of **nt** followed by an **n** sound as in *Clinton*.  In *Clinton*, **nt** often reduces to /n/ followed by a glottal stop /ʔ/: /ˈklɪ̃nʔn̩/, and not /ˈklɪntən/ which remains possible.

Comment: @Araucaria  So "Clinton" rhyming with "linen"?

Comment: Not for speakers like me who have two KIT vowels in *linen*, but yes.

Comment: I'm American, and I think /ˈklɪntən/ sounds perfectly normal (as do /ˈklɪ̃nʔn̩/ and /ˈklɪnən/). You can hear all these pronunciations on [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/search/Clinton/en_usa/).

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for the link!  A quick survey on youtube, made possible by how often the name is pronounced in the news, seems to give /ˈklɪ̃nʔn̩/ as the more usual pronunciation over /ˈklɪntən/.  I couldn't find any instance of /ˈklɪnən/, though, apart for one of the Forvo realizations of the name.

Comment: @petitrien: It's possible /ˈklɪnən/ may be too informal for newscasters to use much.

Comment: Any comments on BrE? (I realize the OP is about AmE)

Comment: @PeterShor There's the _separate_ phenomenon of intervocalic t-lenition in AmE - 'button': /ˈbʌtən/ -> /ˈbʌɾən/ ->/ˈbʌʔən/ . (where /ɾ/ is a tap) 'Clinton' for me is /klinɾən/ (/ən/ is really a syllabic /n/).