# Why does letter 'P' is not doubled in jumping but in mapping?

Tags: suffixes

I just find out that 'jumping' is not doubled P but 'mapping' is and really don't know the rule for this.

Further explanation links are welcomed.

Comment: Double the final consonant when adding *-ing* if the preceding vowel would otherwise change from short to long. Jumping still retains the short u sound; 'maping' would rhyme with 'shaping' if phonetic pronunciation rules were followed. 'Rap' -> 'rapping', which is different from *raping*. As with all things English, exceptions are not uncommon.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a rule, or for words that are formed in similar ways to be spelled in similar ways?  That's not how English spelling works.

Comment: What about _bussing_ and _busing_?

Comment: @JohnLawler - You don't know the difference between kissing and riding public transit?

Comment: How about _busing_ and _abusing_, then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any rhyme or reason to when one should double the last consonant when adding -ed or -ing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5200/is-there-any-rhyme-or-reason-to-when-one-should-double-the-last-consonant-when-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a verb ends with a letter sequence of consonant-vowel-consonant, double the final consonant.

JUMP: vowel(U)-consonant(M)-consonant(P)  => Do not double the final consonant.

MAP: consonant(M)-vowel(A)-consonant(P)   => Double the final consonant.

This rule exempts when h,w,x,or y is the final consonant. Those letters are not doubled.

Comment: Moreover, the rule doesn't apply if the last syllable is weak (e.g. developing).

And when the last letter is C, you add a K (e.g. panicking).