# "Canceling" or "cancelling"

Tags: orthography, gerunds, doubled-consonants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is “L” doubled?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338/when-is-l-doubled)

I'm confused about the two spellings. In which contexts do I have to use *canceling* or *cancelling*?

Google returns 15.6 million results with [canceling](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=canceling) and 18 million with [cancelling](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=cancelling), so I don't know what is the good spelling.
Why are both possible, and are there other such pairs?

Comment: Hi Scorpi0. Welcome to the site. We encourage users to look up words in an online resource, like [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cancelling) before posting, since these source can answer basic questions like this.

Comment: Sorry Matt but I don't see the explanation on Dictionnary.com. The other question contains the answers I look for, so thank to pointing me on this!

Comment: I believe he's referring to "canceling (especially British)," which is not easily noticed if you're not looking for it. Wiktionary has the opposite take. And [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cancelling-or-canceling.318079/) has a whole thread on it. From there: The general rule is that the final consonant is doubled **if** the final syllable is stressed. The exception to this rule is words ending in “l” in [British English] are always doubled.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are many words that have different accepted spellings between British and American English.

The [wiktionary.org entry for "cancelling"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cancelling) says:

> Alternative forms
>
> · canceling (US English)

This implies that a single "l" is preferred in American English and a double "l" in British English.

Comment: Of note: single "l" in American English only preferred (meaning used more often) since the early 1980's actually. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=canceled%2Ccancelled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccanceled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccancelled%3B%2Cc0. We're lazy of late :)

Comment: trends indicate that the triple "l" willl soon be preferrred.