# Spelling of the word "Cancelled"

Tags: orthography

Long ago in grade school we were taught the correct spelling WAS "Cancelled." When did they (spelling police?) decide it is "Canceled?" Personally drives me nuts. I dislike flying and try to avoid it. Being at a airport during heavy thunderstorms and seeing every board with flights that are "Canceled" trips my OCD.
Spelling differences between US & UK, however, I find interesting.

Comment: See related thread, [_When is “L” doubled?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338/when-is-l-doubled) Also, [_“Cancellation”, “Canceled”, “Canceling” — US usage."_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176957/cancellation-canceled-canceling-us-usage) [_“Cancelled” or “Canceled”?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/cancelled-or-canceled/9199) and [_“Canceling” or “cancelling.”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42745/canceling-or-cancelling)

Comment: I think the referenced question answers this. If not, please edit this question (rather than asking a new one) to say why it doesn't.

Comment: An "excellent" question in my "judgement."  See, there are many words whose preferred spelling has evolved.  When I was in grade school, "today" was only spelled "to-day."

Comment: I apologize. Is there a way you could contact me privately? I am new, and would appreciate some clarification please.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, the verb cancel is usually inflected canceled and canceling—with one l. This is not a rule, however, and exceptions are easily found. In varieties of English from outside the U.S., including Canadian, British, and Australian English, cancelled and cancelling are the preferred spellings.

The spelling distinction extends to cancelers and cancellers, as well as to cancelable and cancellable, but it does not not extend to cancellation, which everywhere is spelled with two l’s.

Comment: [US also cancelation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cancellation?q=cancelation)