# Do metaphorical agents follow special rules?

Tags: prepositions, metaphors, predicative-complements

While I can easily parse this sentence, something feels grammatically incorrect and I can't figure out what rule would make it right or wrong.

> "Fatigue from traveling had him in bed by midnight."

I've tried replacing the words to look at it in other ways, but I still get confused. For example "His mother had him in the car before sunrise." In this case, it sounds like the sentence is missing a verb?

Comment: Why would you think there was a problem?

Comment: It hits my ear wrong. So I asked.

Comment: I don't see anything 'wrong' with it but it is an interesting sentence for more than one reason. 'Fatigue [...] _put_ him to bed [...]' I agree would be a bit odd.

Comment: I don't see or hear anything unusual about the sentence. But if it does not ring right, then change it.

Comment: @NigelJ Americans often [spell traveling with one L](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80346/travelling-vs-traveling).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks. I have edited it back again.

Comment: Seems straight out of ODO def 6, which includes *I soon had the trout in a net’*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the matter has nothing to do with grammaticality.

Comment: I can't use *had* in that sentence, but I can use *saw*. Fatigue from traveling saw him in bed by midnight.

Comment: I've re-read the rules, and did my best to rephrase my question so that it's not "off topic."

Comment: Close voters, again: English language does include English semantics and pragmatics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *construction* includes a syntactic frame and an associated meaning.

The example seems weird to you because the construction `X have [passive S]` has a meaning that X caused S to happen indirectly, and usually intentionally: e.g.,

> I'll have you thrown out on the streets!

Since `fatigue` is not an intentional agent, it's a metaphorical use of the construction, which is why it sounds a bit odd at first, but the metaphorical meaning is clear.