# What's the difference between 'modeling' and 'modelling'?

Tags: meaning, doubled-consonants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is “L” doubled?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338/when-is-l-doubled)

If I am using the word *model* in the context of financial models and the UK, then which of these words should I use? Also, are there any key difference in the meanings of the two?

Comment: @FumbleFingers and RegDwight: If this is a duplicate, please link to the duplicate. The Possible Duplicate listed (*When is "L" doubled?*) is *not* a true duplicate. The answer is the same, but the question has a different context than the listed Possible Duplicate, which is more general. A "see also" might be more appropriate than marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning.  The single-L spelling is more common in the United States; the double-L spelling is more common in the United Kingdom, Australia, South Africa and New Zealand.  I don't know which is more common in other countries.

More detail is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_in_British_English

Comment: _programmed_, _programming_ and _programmer_ ?  Do these three seriously exist with a single M?

Comment: I'm a programmer and I frequently see 'build canceled' on Microsoft programming products.  In fact, it seems that Microsoft were unable to tell a complainant how to change Microsoft Outlook to say 'Meeting Cancelled', despite a UK language pack being applied.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no difference between them.  *Modelling* is the more common spelling in the UK, while *modeling* is the more common spelling in the US.  Canada tends to use *modelling*, as do some Americans.