# Spined or Spinned (Spin)

Tags: grammar

Roulette wheel spins.
That is I made it spin (sorry don't know how to say this)

Was the wheel spinned or spined?

How do I say what happened to the wheel once I spin it?

Comment: Spin -> span -> spun.

Comment: ah, I would never figure that out, so the wheel was spun? thanks.

Comment: Yep, *wheel was spun.* (Also, it would be 'spined' if its first form was 'spine'. You'll find more details in [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532277/why-dont-we-double-the-final-consonant-in-the-word-cooking/532376#532376) question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spin > Spinned*

Spine > Spined*

If the syllable in one-syllable words have the structure of (C)CVC, the last consonant is doubled when suffixes are added, eg. stopped, tipped etc.

EDIT This is only theoretical as an answer to your n/nn question since 'spin' is irregular (with 'spun' as its preterite/participle) and 'spined' is, I believe, an adjective found only in combinations like 'broken-spined'

Comment: You should reiterate, though, that the proper past tense is "spun".

Comment: I think the example of 'spinned' is misleading.