# Why is double -ll- used after a vowel digraph in "surveilled, surveilling"?

Tags: american-english, orthography, doubled-consonants

Why is the letter *l* double in the inflections of the verb **surveil**?

It's not in those of *(as)sail* or *veil*, and AmE has *cance**l**ed* but mostly *cance**ll**ation*. It's a counterintuitive spelling similar to those of *control*.

No wonder some people write it as [surveill**e**](https://books.google.es/books?id=FwmQpyibKkAC&lpg=PA790&ots=40e5yOSUg4&dq=%22The%20spelling%20%E2%9C%B3surveille%20is%20a%20variant%20form.%22&hl=es&pg=PA790#v=onepage&q=%22The%20spelling%20%E2%9C%B3surveille%20is%20a%20variant%20form.%22&f=false)

Per [Decapitated Soul's answer to *When is "L" doubled?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/533791):

> The **-l-** after a *digraph* or a diphthong does not
> usually get doubled.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - Prevail -> prevai**l**ed not prevai**ll**ed.
> - Detail -> detai**l**ed not detai**ll**ed.
> - Mail -> mai**l**ed not mai**ll**ed.

Why is *surveilled, surveilling* an exception?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul what do you call _syllable_ exactly? what about _sailed_, _assailed_ and _veiled_ ?

Comment: @herisson I am confused. Why is it still a duplicate even after your editing?

Comment: In any event, it makes no difference to English, since (a) the /l/ isn't doubled, (b) the rule confuses digraphs and diphthongs, (c) there is no definitive rule. All spelling is just printers' conventions, which change with printing technology and don't change with the language.

Comment: @herisson: You're right. I didn't realise there was a digraph there... I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess it's because it is a back formation from *surveillance,* which is spelled with two Ls. As you noted, some people use the spelling *surveille.*

The noun *surveillance* remains much more common than any form of the verb:

[image]

([Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surveilled%2Csurveillance%2C+surveilling%2C+surveil&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csurveilled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveillance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveilling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveil%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csurveilled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveillance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveilling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurveil%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: +1 *surveillance* is from French.  Some few Amerians even pronounce it like "survey-ance".